# How to introduce delay(waiting loop) in simulink between two independent models

Tags: simulink

I am having a model in simulink consisting of two parts one of image processing and other of control systems. I want to introduce delay(waiting loop) between the two independent models i.e when image processing part and controller part is simulated once I want to introduce some delay before the second simulation.How can I do this? any help???

Comment: can you mark the question answered if you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

you can put between them a [Delay block](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/simulink/slref/delay.html) z^-1  specifiing the delay or create a stateflow block with your logic and delays.

note: there are olso a delay for continus function, see what fit best for you